# What Projectiles can Mario/Dr. Mario's Cape Reflect?

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee

The SSB wiki quotes the Melee instruction manual on Mario's [cape](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Cape) in stating:

> Reflect projectile attacks and spin enemies around.

**Which projectiles are actually reflected?**

Is it all projectiles? Is it limited to energy projectiles (eg. Fox/Falco's [Blaster](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Blaster_(Fox)))? Are non-energy projectiles (like Yoshi's [Egg Throw](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Egg_Throw) or Link's [Hero's Bow](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Hero%27s_Bow)) reflected? Unless all projectiles are reflected, a good answer would provide a list of all those projectiles that are actually reflected.

For reference, I have found [this list](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Projectile) of all projectiles in the SSB universe.

Comment: I *think* it's all of them, but I'm not 100% certain

Comment: @JonK Yeah I think it's probably most, but not sure if it's all of them, hence the question :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this forum](https://smashboards.com/threads/what-mario-can-deflect.369560/), the cape can deflect all projectiles:

> Mario's cape can reflect literally any projectile (like Villager's bowling ball and falling tree, and Megaman's charge shot) that isn't an explosive. Explosives tend to explode when hit by the cape, but the damage is reflected.

Although the forum appears to be talking about a different Super Smash Bros, I believe it upholds, since the cape is considered a reflector (see below). The thing with explosive projectiles is that they will blow up instead, but the damage is reflected.  In my time playing Melee, this is how I remember it as well.

According to [the Wiki page for reflection](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Reflection), the cape is considered a reflector.  On the same page, it lists all items that are able to be reflected, including character abilities and the environmental projectiles.  Ignoring those, it states in the table for items that "All Thrown Items" are reflectable.

According to the link you added in your question, the only ability I see that may not be reflectable is Sheik's [Vanish](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Vanish) ability, which is considered a projectile according to that page. There are a few others in that list that aren't, but they are for characters that do not exist in Melee.

Comment: If the answer is referencing Villager and Megaman, then it is probably referencing SSB: Brawl, and not SSB: Melee

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein I still think it upholds. I'll see if I can find any differences between versions.

Comment: Yeah if you find a source verifying its the same I'm happy to accept

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein I think the Wiki page linked in my answer is the best bet.  The cape (or really *reflectors*) doesn't appear to have changed across the years between the games with the exception of when an item is reflected too many times it either (depending on the game) stuns the person trying to reflect it, or ignored the reflector completely.

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein Villager and Megaman were added in SSB4, not Brawl.

Comment: Hmm, alright. I think I will respectfully wait for another couple hours to see if any other answers come in confirming or denying any changes in reflecting since Melee, otherwise I'll accept this answer

Comment: @MageXy, thanks for the heads up; even more of a reason to wait for a stronger link between melee and subsequent games