# What can be Blocked by the Hylian and Deku Shields?

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee

Building off of my [previous](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/309825/what-projectiles-can-mario-dr-marios-cape-reflect) [questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310225/what-is-special-about-yoshis-egg-shield) on the [topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310137/what-can-peachs-neutral-special-toad-guard-actually-block),

**What can be blocked by both Link and Young Link's shields?**

Here when I say shield, I do not mean the shields used by *all* characters, but rather the Hylian Shield (for Link) and the Deku shield (Young Link).

The only descriptions I could find are the following from [Link's wiki](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Link_(SSBM)#Attributes_2):

> Link's Hylian Shield now has a hitbox that allows it to nullify projectiles.

and from [Young Link's wiki](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Young_Link_(SSBM)#Attributes_2):

> Young Link's Deku Shield is weaker than the Hylian Shield in protection, as projectiles that are strong enough will ignore and penetrate through the shield.

So more specifically, what projectiles will be blocked by Link's Hylian Shield, and how would this change for Young Link's Deku Shield? Are [all projectiles](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Projectile) blocked by Link, and if so, which would NOT be blocked by Young Link's Deku Shield?

Answer (score 1):

In short, most projectiles can be blocked by Link and Young Link's shields.

This [wiki](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Shield_(Link)) about Link's shield states:

> To be considered a projectile for the purposes of the shield, a hitbox must be reflectable and not unblockable.

There is no distinction made between Link and Young Link (or Toon Link for that matter). However, Link's shield in Smash 64 does not block anything.

This [wiki](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Projectile) lists all of the Smash series projectiles and whether or not they are reflectable (and in which Smash, if different).